# How Spring hibernate integration is beneficial

Tags: hibernate, spring-orm

When we integrate hibernate in spring then what part of work spring do on behalf of hibernate? what are benefits of doing this integration.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate is an JPA implementation, it is not directly related to Spring. However you are most likely ending up using it by Spring JPA or Spring data. Both let you inject an Entitymanager, the JPA interface. If necessary you can unwrap a HibernateSession an use it directly, thats sometimes useful for dynamic queries.

**Tl;dr**: look up the terms ORM and JPA.